# How do I prevent div containers from moving due to an element's padding?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a table-like display for my list of archives on my blog. Structure is as follows:

```css
a, a:active, a:visited { 
    color: rgb(140, 155, 196); 
    text-decoration: none; 
    transition: all ease-in-out 0.1s;
}

a:hover {
    border-bottom: rgba(111, 122, 153, 0.8) 1px dotted; 
    color: #3A414B;
    transition: all ease-in-out 0.1s;
}

.archives-list {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.archives-list .archive {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin: 0.3rem 0;
    padding: 0.1rem;
}

.archives-list .archive .archive-date {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-right: 0.8rem;
    font-size: small;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #3A414B;
    min-width: 15%;
}

.archives-list .archive .archive-link {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="archives-list">
      <div class="archive">
          <div class="archive-date">Apr 4 2018</div>
          <a class="archive-link" href="/some/link">some post</a>
      </div>
</div>
<div class="archives-list">
      <div class="archive">
          <div class="archive-date">Apr 4 2018</div>
          <a class="archive-link" href="/some/link">some post</a>
      </div>
</div>
```

...basically a dotted border-bottom appears upon hovering over a link. So what I observed is that the `archive-link` container adds a bottom padding every time I hover on an archive-link, making all the other elements below it move a little. It's a little bothersome for someone very nitpick-y with the tiniest pixels.

I'm still a beginner with flexbox so I tried using other display types but the behavior persists. For now this is what sort of works for the look that I'm going for (sans the moving stuff).

Which is the culprit of padding the containers, and how can the CSS be modified so that the elements don't nudge? Thanks!

Comment: Your link has a `1px` border when hovered. When it's not hovered, it doesn't. This may be the cause of your issue. Try adding a `1px` transparent border to the link when it's not hovered and see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

By attaching a border to the bottom of the link you are actually increasing the height of the element by a single pixel while not actually adding any padding.

There are a few ways around this.

The first being that you could use text-decoration properties to give it a dotted underline instead of a border which wouldn't cause the height of the link to grow at all.

The second being you could offset the height grow in the other direction with a negative margin by having a `margin-top: -1px` on the hover rule. This however would be noticeable as it will appear to shift.

The third thing you can try is giving it a defined height and telling it to be a border box.
Example: https://jsfiddle.net/o5bam9hp/2/

Probably the easier way to deal with it would be to have a transparent border around the entire link. Then coloring in the bottom portion on a hover event.This will keep the element from growing or shifting as you are just transitioning a color really.
Example: https://jsfiddle.net/m6qkjL50/